# How could I access an object inside the function context?

Tags: php

How could I access `$test` object inside the function context?

```
$test = new test();

function foo(){
   echo $test->method();
}
```

Important to point out that solutions such as sending arguments and global would not be ideal.

"use" keyword doesn't work in this case.

```
function foo () use (&$test) {
}
```

Is there a more elegant way to do this?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php

Comment: If you dont want to pass it as an argument, you could declare `global` inside foo function

Comment: it would be impracticable to send as an argument

Comment: use as a global ... I do not know if it would be interesting

Comment: If arguments and global don't work then your question needs to be updated with this information and explanation.

Comment: Thanks Dan88, I already did this

Comment: Why is an argument not ideal? To me it is the best way.

Comment: `use` is only for anonymous functions (closures) http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php.  You have two main ways, arguments or global.  Aside from that, stick it in a registry class and retrieve it.

Answer (score 1):

Under your constraints. I doubt so.

Read [PHP.net - Variables Scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) first, and you will know that you don`t have any choice in terms of the scope of the variable: $test is not global and you hate arguments? No luck.

Comment: So there are only these two options, my point is to find the best option, and maybe some that I did not know. But I loved the receptiveness of the group.

Comment: It is right. It will take time to gather all pieces of information to find the best option. As all other mentioned, unlike javascript, php does not really have such scopes of variable to achieve what you asked (e.g. declaration by "let"). The best shot could be a class variable (static) to store the value, but that somehow is still global.